# Installing libjson-rpc-perl on Linux

Tags: linux, perl, json-rpc, zabbix, libjson

I am trying to install **libjson-rpc-perl** on my linux server but facing an error. Could anyone guide me in right direction ?

**Details :**

```
09:04:02 # lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)
Release:        6.2
Codename:       Santiago
```

**Installing :**

(perl) - done

```
09:01:26 # yum list available 'perl'
Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
```

(libjson-rpc-perl) - ERROR

```
09:03:40 # sudo yum install libjson-rpc-perl
Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Setting up Install Process
No package libjson-rpc-perl available.
Error: Nothing to do
root@zabbix_server:/root
```

Comment: That package name format looks more like debian than redhat to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats definitely a debian package name, not a redhat one.  Have had a search for the redhat package [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/) but there doesn't seem to be one

Answer (score 2):

Install the package via your CPAN client; or (have someone) create an RPM package for it, and install that.